# Can I query Wikidata for Wikimedia images related to an entity using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikimedia

I know I can query Wikipedia pages from Wikidata like this:

```
SELECT ?place ?article WHERE {
  SERVICE wikibase:box {
    ?place wdt:P625 ?location .
    # looks like cornerwest must be south of cornereast
    # otherwise you go around the globe
    # this is lng lat
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:cornerWest "Point(1 12)"^^geo:wktLiteral .
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:cornerEast "Point(2 13)"^^geo:wktLiteral .
  }
      ?article schema:about ?place .
      ?article schema:isPartOf [ wikibase:wikiGroup "wikipedia" ] .
}
```

and I know that - given an article title - I can query its images using the Wikipedia API like this:

```
https://pl.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Pearl_Harbor&format=json&prop=images
```

([link](https://pl.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Pearl_Harbor&format=json&prop=images) to results).

I would like to do that in one go - is that possible?

Comment: did you try to use the Wikidata image property `wdt:P18` ?

Comment: @UninformedUser yes - but it provides only one image as far as I can see. My goal is to get all images related to a page

Comment: Ok, yeah, the Wikidata entity of Pearl Harbor has only one image: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q127091 - but to be fair, Wikidata is not Wikipedia. In Wikiedata itself that data is most likely not contained, but there are those generators: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual/MWAPI#Get_imageusage - not sure, if this could be used in combination